# Unable to login to MYSQL getting error ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, database, fedora

I am not able to connect to mysql server getting error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I have checked log :-

```
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
130820  5:19:41  InnoDB: Error: the OS said file flush did not succeed
130820  5:19:41  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 5 means 'Input/output error'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File operation call: 'flush'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
130820 05:19:42  mysqld ended
```

Due to this am not able to restart or start mysql

```
[root@OPX-VPC-DB-Report-Slave-2 ~]# service mysqld status
mysqld is stopped
[root@OPX-VPC-DB-Report-Slave-2 ~]# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
Timeout error occurred trying to start MySQL Daemon.
Starting MySQL:                                            [FAILED]
[root@OPX-VPC-DB-Report-Slave-2 ~]#
```

I have searched a lot on internet but not found any solution

I have configured RAID 0 and mount /mnt  directory and symlinc

```
# ln -s /mnt/mysql_data/   /usr/lib/mysql
# ln -s /mnt/mysql_run     /var/run/mysql
```

Yesterday there is an replication crashed so i have ran

```
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1;
```

And again the replication is fine

Please resolve my problem

My configuration details is :"-

```
Fedora 6 and mysql 5.0.2

Please help this is my production DB
```

Comment: Write your question [title short](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/159344)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a permission issue, try disabling selinuza by using setenforce 0, then restart the mysql service, also check if mysql has the right permissions on the mounted device (assuming you mounted as root or a sudo user that mysql cannot access)

Comment: I have mounted directories with mysql Permission and my SELINUX is disabled 

drwxrwxrwx 6 mysql mysql  4096 Aug 20 05:47 mysql_data
drwxrwxrwx 2 mysql mysql    81 Aug 19 09:35 mysql_run
drwxrwxrwx 2 mysql mysql    27 Aug 20 05:47 mysql_tmp