# Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock’ (2) Fedora Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora, command-line-interface

I'm having the problem described in title.

I have tried the solutions given here: [Unable to login to MYSQL getting error ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327609/unable-to-login-to-mysql-getting-error-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-loca) and here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-varlibmysqlmysql-sock-2/

Please help me. Im using fedora 18 and MySQL 5.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 for putting versions of SO and MySQL and made a research before posting answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What i can think right now if you've already tried the solutions in your link, is that SELinux (Fedora's) is blocking service.

try

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

and then

```
sudo service mysqld start
```

let me know if it helped please

Comment: It Works, but what is that SELinux all about? long story short please.

Comment: It's an additional security measure on a Linux system. Not for all distros. Give this a read: http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your mysqld is running correctly?
If you stop the mysqld and restart it, are there any logs created stating that there's a problem starting up?

Answer (score 0):

Just to remind those who have downloaded mariadb and accounted the same problem: if you download mariadb, you have to download both client and server-if you just download client, same error would happen.